# Parsing a website with is not working with "fromestring" in python

Tags: python, xml, url

I'm trying to retrieve data from a xml website through "fromstring" of xml.etree.ElementTree.
The python code works fine for the test link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml, but it doesn't work for the link that we'll be using: https://griddata.elia.be/eliabecontrols.prod/interface/oneminuteimbalance/SystemImbalancePrice

I've double checked if the url is correct and it is. The content of both website seems to be read differently, would someone have some advice?

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml')
print(r.content)
tree = ET.fromstring(r.content)


r = requests.get('https://griddata.elia.be/eliabecontrols.prod/interface/oneminuteimbalance/SystemImbalancePrice')
print(r.content)
tree = ET.fromstring(r.content)
```

I get the following print of first website, which is oké:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<CATALOG>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1973</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1999</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1971</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>T\'Pau</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Stax Records</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1968</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n  <CD>\n    <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>\n  </CD>\n</CATALOG>\n'
```

Print of second website with error. Note that the content is differently printed in comparison to the previous url, the "<" or ">" are replaced by [ { and :

```
b'[{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:01:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":106.419,"si":-129.067,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:02:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":130.253,"si":-149.373,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:03:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":141.184,"si":-154.362,"alpha":1.06,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":76.06,"pneg":76.06,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:04:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":134.060,"si":-145.134,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:05:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":126.640,"si":-135.213,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:06:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":123.714,"si":-131.696,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:07:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":122.662,"si":-128.840,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:08:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":117.235,"si":-122.387,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:09:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":107.319,"si":-112.476,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:10:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":96.516,"si":-99.953,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:11:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":84.115,"si":-86.453,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:12:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":71.897,"si":-74.181,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:13:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":63.499,"si":-65.518,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:00:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:14:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":56.331,"si":-58.580,"alpha":0.00,"mip":75.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":75.00,"pneg":75.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":34.315,"si":-50.389,"alpha":0.00,"mip":105.24,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":105.24,"pneg":105.24,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:16:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":53.182,"si":-59.704,"alpha":0.00,"mip":103.17,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":103.17,"pneg":103.17,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:17:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":56.326,"si":-60.755,"alpha":0.00,"mip":99.15,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":99.15,"pneg":99.15,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:18:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":66.387,"si":-71.924,"alpha":0.00,"mip":96.15,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":96.15,"pneg":96.15,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:19:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":74.512,"si":-77.766,"alpha":0.00,"mip":93.43,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":93.43,"pneg":93.43,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:20:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":71.570,"si":-72.336,"alpha":0.00,"mip":91.92,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":91.92,"pneg":91.92,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:21:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":62.541,"si":-63.838,"alpha":0.00,"mip":91.28,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":91.28,"pneg":91.28,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:22:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":58.370,"si":-60.315,"alpha":0.00,"mip":91.16,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":91.16,"pneg":91.16,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:23:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":54.269,"si":-55.793,"alpha":0.00,"mip":90.38,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":90.38,"pneg":90.38,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:24:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":53.270,"si":-54.102,"alpha":0.00,"mip":89.61,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":89.61,"pneg":89.61,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:25:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":49.977,"si":-51.507,"alpha":0.00,"mip":88.81,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":88.81,"pneg":88.81,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:26:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":46.909,"si":-47.750,"alpha":0.00,"mip":88.11,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":88.11,"pneg":88.11,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:27:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":43.660,"si":-44.609,"alpha":0.00,"mip":87.70,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":87.70,"pneg":87.70,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:28:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":43.854,"si":-45.002,"alpha":0.00,"mip":87.41,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":87.41,"pneg":87.41,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:15:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:29:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":43.342,"si":-44.038,"alpha":0.00,"mip":86.89,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":86.89,"pneg":86.89,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":31.716,"si":-48.580,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:31:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":45.300,"si":-57.368,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:32:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":60.071,"si":-80.431,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:33:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":60.922,"si":-84.020,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:34:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":63.860,"si":-85.537,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:35:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":63.416,"si":-82.515,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:36:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":61.651,"si":-76.046,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:37:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":56.821,"si":-66.456,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:38:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":49.664,"si":-58.244,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:39:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":46.889,"si":-55.661,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:40:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":44.011,"si":-52.397,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:41:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":44.113,"si":-51.902,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:42:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":46.574,"si":-53.290,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:43:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":46.391,"si":-52.858,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:30:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:44:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":49.648,"si":-56.503,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":118.982,"si":-118.880,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:46:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":122.491,"si":-123.807,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:47:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":137.171,"si":-137.017,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:48:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":143.317,"si":-143.904,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:49:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":149.831,"si":-152.459,"alpha":0.93,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.93,"pneg":115.93,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:50:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":162.638,"si":-165.874,"alpha":1.03,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":116.03,"pneg":116.03,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:51:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":165.350,"si":-161.391,"alpha":1.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":116.00,"pneg":116.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:52:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":148.814,"si":-146.664,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:53:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":138.935,"si":-137.614,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:54:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":130.209,"si":-128.994,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:55:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":123.182,"si":-120.632,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:56:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":112.202,"si":-108.525,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:57:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":102.194,"si":-95.053,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:58:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":92.616,"si":-82.364,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true},{"quarter":"2021-07-28T12:45:00Z","minute":"2021-07-28T12:59:00Z","status":"Non-validated","nrv":83.382,"si":-67.439,"alpha":0.00,"mip":115.00,"mdp":5.00,"sr":null,"ssi":null,"ppos":115.00,"pneg":115.00,"isVisible":true}]'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "N:\Energie-JP\Onbalans\Python\house-price-prediction-master\house-price-prediction-master\xml Elia.py", line 12, in <module>
        tree = ET.fromstring(r.content)
      File "C:\Users\driesvds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1347, in XML
        parser.feed(text)
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below return a list of dicts. Not XML

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://griddata.elia.be/eliabecontrols.prod/interface/oneminuteimbalance/SystemImbalancePrice').json()
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:37:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -356.557, 'si': 351.557, 'alpha': 23.2, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -18.2, 'pneg': -18.2, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:38:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -356.962, 'si': 347.403, 'alpha': 22.55, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -17.55, 'pneg': -17.55, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:39:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -353.404, 'si': 343.054, 'alpha': 21.89, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -16.89, 'pneg': -16.89, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:40:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -350.7, 'si': 340.848, 'alpha': 21.56, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -16.56, 'pneg': -16.56, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:41:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -344.857, 'si': 330.082, 'alpha': 20.02, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -15.02, 'pneg': -15.02, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:42:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -315.466, 'si': 301.072, 'alpha': 16.34, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -11.34, 'pneg': -11.34, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:43:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -289.705, 'si': 276.885, 'alpha': 13.76, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -8.76, 'pneg': -8.76, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:44:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -269.121, 'si': 257.056, 'alpha': 11.93, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -6.93, 'pneg': -6.93, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -299.384, 'si': 304.58, 'alpha': 14.01, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -98.01, 'pneg': -98.01, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:46:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -316.181, 'si': 318.492, 'alpha': 15.47, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -99.47, 'pneg': -99.47, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:47:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -313.309, 'si': 314.143, 'alpha': 15.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -99.0, 'pneg': -99.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:48:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -315.46, 'si': 317.905, 'alpha': 15.4, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -99.4, 'pneg': -99.4, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:49:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -319.519, 'si': 320.706, 'alpha': 15.71, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -99.71, 'pneg': -99.71, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:50:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -312.971, 'si': 308.902, 'alpha': 14.45, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -98.45, 'pneg': -98.45, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:51:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -294.42, 'si': 287.356, 'alpha': 12.38, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -96.38, 'pneg': -96.38, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:52:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -277.232, 'si': 269.214, 'alpha': 10.85, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -94.85, 'pneg': -94.85, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:53:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -254.143, 'si': 247.273, 'alpha': 9.25, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -93.25, 'pneg': -93.25, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:54:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -232.978, 'si': 228.535, 'alpha': 8.05, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -92.05, 'pneg': -92.05, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:55:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -217.338, 'si': 213.319, 'alpha': 7.2, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -91.2, 'pneg': -91.2, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:56:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -204.198, 'si': 200.474, 'alpha': 6.54, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -90.54, 'pneg': -90.54, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:57:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -196.092, 'si': 192.137, 'alpha': 6.15, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -90.15, 'pneg': -90.15, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:58:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -187.735, 'si': 182.717, 'alpha': 5.73, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.73, 'pneg': -89.73, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T13:45:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T13:59:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -183.187, 'si': 179.796, 'alpha': 5.61, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.61, 'pneg': -89.61, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -153.631, 'si': 162.94, 'alpha': 2.74, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -86.74, 'pneg': -86.74, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:01:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -170.926, 'si': 172.994, 'alpha': 2.96, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -86.96, 'pneg': -86.96, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:02:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -163.061, 'si': 165.785, 'alpha': 2.8, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -86.8, 'pneg': -86.8, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:03:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -173.522, 'si': 177.362, 'alpha': 3.06, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -87.06, 'pneg': -87.06, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:04:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -186.198, 'si': 191.067, 'alpha': 3.39, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -87.39, 'pneg': -87.39, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:05:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -204.776, 'si': 210.282, 'alpha': 3.92, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -87.92, 'pneg': -87.92, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:06:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -226.479, 'si': 231.999, 'alpha': 4.62, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -88.62, 'pneg': -88.62, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:07:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -241.001, 'si': 245.457, 'alpha': 5.11, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.11, 'pneg': -89.11, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:08:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -251.374, 'si': 254.502, 'alpha': 5.47, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.47, 'pneg': -89.47, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:09:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -256.502, 'si': 260.089, 'alpha': 5.7, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.7, 'pneg': -89.7, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:10:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -260.078, 'si': 263.7, 'alpha': 5.86, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.86, 'pneg': -89.86, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:11:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -263.115, 'si': 266.25, 'alpha': 5.97, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -89.97, 'pneg': -89.97, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:12:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -264.613, 'si': 267.072, 'alpha': 6.01, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -90.01, 'pneg': -90.01, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:13:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -265.208, 'si': 268.545, 'alpha': 6.08, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -90.08, 'pneg': -90.08, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:00:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:14:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -269.303, 'si': 272.157, 'alpha': 6.24, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -90.24, 'pneg': -90.24, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -269.024, 'si': 260.676, 'alpha': 11.92, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -95.92, 'pneg': -95.92, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:16:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -262.886, 'si': 255.004, 'alpha': 11.44, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -95.44, 'pneg': -95.44, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:17:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -255.203, 'si': 253.659, 'alpha': 11.33, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -95.33, 'pneg': -95.33, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:18:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -256.661, 'si': 254.938, 'alpha': 11.44, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -95.44, 'pneg': -95.44, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:19:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -256.507, 'si': 255.651, 'alpha': 11.5, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -95.5, 'pneg': -95.5, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:20:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -251.793, 'si': 250.832, 'alpha': 11.1, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -95.1, 'pneg': -95.1, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:21:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -245.126, 'si': 247.121, 'alpha': 10.81, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -94.81, 'pneg': -94.81, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:22:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -240.617, 'si': 244.357, 'alpha': 10.59, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -94.59, 'pneg': -94.59, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:23:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -233.325, 'si': 234.621, 'alpha': 9.86, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -93.86, 'pneg': -93.86, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:24:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -222.396, 'si': 224.383, 'alpha': 9.15, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -93.15, 'pneg': -93.15, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:25:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -217.976, 'si': 218.657, 'alpha': 8.77, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -92.77, 'pneg': -92.77, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:26:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -208.323, 'si': 209.585, 'alpha': 8.21, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -92.21, 'pneg': -92.21, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:27:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -204.128, 'si': 205.889, 'alpha': 7.99, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -91.99, 'pneg': -91.99, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:28:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -202.255, 'si': 203.441, 'alpha': 7.84, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -91.84, 'pneg': -91.84, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:15:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:29:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -197.538, 'si': 198.811, 'alpha': 7.58, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': -84.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': -91.58, 'pneg': -91.58, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': 72.548, 'si': -80.548, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 115.0, 'pneg': 115.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:31:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': 1.453, 'si': 7.256, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 5.0, 'pneg': 5.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:32:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -44.206, 'si': 50.822, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 5.0, 'pneg': 5.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:33:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -75.133, 'si': 78.866, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 5.0, 'pneg': 5.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:34:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -91.547, 'si': 104.315, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 5.0, 'pneg': 5.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:35:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -106.934, 'si': 124.789, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 5.0, 'pneg': 5.0, 'isVisible': True}, {'quarter': '2021-07-28T14:30:00Z', 'minute': '2021-07-28T14:36:00Z', 'status': 'Non-validated', 'nrv': -119.707, 'si': 132.999, 'alpha': 0.0, 'mip': 115.0, 'mdp': 5.0, 'sr': None, 'ssi': None, 'ppos': 5.0, 'pneg': 5.0, 'isVisible': True}]
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know the reason why the website 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml') returns an xml and the website 'https://griddata.elia.be/eliabecontrols.prod/interface/oneminuteimbalance/SystemImbalancePrice returns the list of dicts?

Comment: No special reason... It is just a fact.